# Android json parsing object inside another object and array

Tags: android, json

I want parse all "name" and "desc" from this json object inside another json object. i need another "for"?

```
 {
  "main": {
    "details": [
      {
        "owner_name": "owner_name1",
        "id": "id1",
        "details2": {
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "name1",
              "desc": "my desc1",

            },
            {
              "name": "name2",
              "desc": "my desc2",

            }
          ],

        }
      },
      {
        "owner_name": "owner_name2",
        "id": "id2",
        "details2": {
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "name3",
              "desc": "my desc3",

            },
            {
              "name": "name4",
              "desc": "my desc4",

            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and My java Code is:

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
JSONObject mainObject = jsono.getJSONObject("main");
JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("details");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     JSONObject objectDetails2 = object1.getJSONObject("details2");
     JSONArray jsonArrayData = objectDetails2.getJSONArray("data");

   for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayData.length(); j++) {
         JSONObject object = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(j);   
         Actors actor = new Actors();
    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
    actor.setDesc(object.getString("desc"));


    actorsList.add(actor);

      }
```

It only show First "data" result inside details2 not showing second details2 inside data..
Now my result is: "name1,dmy desc1,name2,my desc2"

i want all result like : "name1,dmy desc1,name2,my desc2,name3,my desc3,name4,my desc4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i go again inside object and array? i need details from "name"
>   and "desc"

Get `details2` from `object` JSONObject and then get `data` JSONArray:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         // get details2 JSONObject
         if(object.has("details2")){
           if(!object.isNUll("details2")){
            JSONObject objectDetails2 = object.getJSONObject("details2");
            // get data JSONArray from objectDetails2
            if(objectDetails2.has("data")){
              if(!objectDetails2.isNUll("data")){
                JSONArray jsonArrayData = objectDetails2.getJSONArray("data");
                 // iterate to jsonArrayData 
                 for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayData.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject objectInner = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    String strName=objectInner.optString("name");
                    ....  
                  }
        }else{
                 // details2 found but null
                }
            }else{
            // details2 not found
            }
         }else{
           // details2 found but null
        }
       }else{
           // details2 not found
       }
}
```

Comment: @Mullinsangebn: debug your code somewhere is breaking after reading first object

Comment: Yes one array dont have details2 and data.. but next one have it... how can i fix it?

Comment: @Mullinsangebn: ok use `isNull` and `has` method for checking `is JSONObject or JSONArray contain details2 or data` if contain then parse other-wise move to next

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go into "details2" JSON Object like this :

```
JSONArray jsonArrayData=object.getJSONObject("details2").getJSONArray("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the object first and then parse it for the diffrent names and info

```
JSONArray jsonArrayData;
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject("details");
    jsonArrayData=object.getJSONArray("data");
    for(int k=0;k<jsonArrayData.length();k++)
      {
    Actors actor = new Actors();
    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
    actor.setDesc(object.getString("desc"));        
    actorsList.add(actor);
   }
 }
```

i will suggest you use GSON it is quite simple to use,